# Grails g:link to call jquery function

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

I'm trying to call a jquery function from a Grails .gsp page using g:link. Is this possible? Currently, I'm using a regular button (which is successful in calling `$( "#opener" )`:

```
<li><button id="opener">Export</button></li>
```

But I am looking to use something like the following:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Export">
    <p>This is a sample dialog...</p>
</div>
<li><g:link class="export">
    <g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" />
</g:link></li>
```

Here is my function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { text-align: center; float: none; }
</style>
<script>

// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        buttons: {
            "OK!": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I needed to do this (Grails 1.3), I ended up just using a standard HTML `<a></a>` link with `onclick`.  For example:

```
<a href="#" class="export" onclick="some_function();"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></a>
```

There might be a way to do this with a Grails taglib now with 2.1.x, but if there I am unaware of it.

Comment: I just tried this, and I am receiving the error "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function". I posted my function above. Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Can you post your relevant GSP content too?

Comment: I fixed the issue using "id" instead of "onclick": <a href="#" class="exp" id="opener">, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Grails 2.5 you can do like this:

```
<g:link onclick="alert('hello world')">
```